# How to make Angular UI carousel full width?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angular ui carousel, it sticks to 800px width and I cannot find which css or html I need to edit to make it full width

this is the actual code:

```
        <carousel interval="slideInterval">
            <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" id="slide-{{slide.id}}">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;"/>
            </slide>
        </carousel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has [grid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), so its width is relative to its parent element. For instance, you can use this for full width carousel:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <carousel interval="slideInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" id="slide-{{slide.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}"/>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```